# Template for similar members of different classes

Tags: c++, templates, generics

Is there a way to implement a template for similar members of different classes?

In the code below two classes differ only by type of the map used in them while all the code in `parse` is similar.

Can I somehow define a template for `parse` function to avoid code duplication here?

```
#include <string_view>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <concurrent_unordered_map.h>

class SingleThreadedParser {
    std::unordered_map<std::string_view, int> dict;
public:
    std::vector<int> parse(std::string_view) {
        std::vector<int> res;
        ///  a lot of code woking with dict 
        return res;
    }
};

class MultithreadedParser {
    Concurrency::concurrent_unordered_map<std::string_view, int> dict;
public:
    std::vector<int> parse(std::string_view) {
        std::vector<int> res;
        ///  a lot of code woking with dict
        return res;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::string some_string = "Test";

    SingleThreadedParser sp;
    MultithreadedParser mp;

    auto sp_res = sp.parse(some_string);
    auto mp_res = mp.parse(some_string);
}
```

The performance is critical so I want to avoid wrapping the maps and using dynamic polymorphism to access them. That's why I am interested in template-based implementation.

Is that possible?

Comment: `template<typename T> void parse(const T& dict) { /* code */ }`?

Comment: No, but you can easily define a template for both classes, and replace them both with a single template. Mission accomplished.

Comment: @NathanOliver, the `dict` is not the only member I use in this method. Would it be better to pass all of them to template or it would be better (possible?) to pass the reference to the class itself?

Comment: @DamirTenishev If the members you want to use have the same name then passing the entire class by reference would work.  Otherwise you could take the parameters you need.  There is also Aedoro's solution below which is a great approach.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, I read your proposal many times, but still failed to figure out what this should be like in code. Can you please draft in a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hqqMbhMPK) the approach you meant?

Comment: It's unclear that my proposal is exactly what the current answer does? I wrote: "define a template for both classes, and replace them both with a single template", and the answer, below, defines that template, and replaces them both with a single template.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, well, now I see what the phrase "code speaks better" means. Thank you, I get it now. The wording was somehow hard for me to get to the point. Seems to be "personal experience".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be what you want.

```cpp
template<template<typename Key, typename Value> typename MapType>
class Parser
{
    MapType<std::string_view, int> dict;
public:
    std::vector<int> parse(std::string_view) {
        std::vector<int> res;
        ///  a lot of code woking with dict 
        return res;
    }
};

using SingleThreadedParser = Parser<std::unordered_map>;
using MultithreadedParser = Parser<Concurrency::concurrent_unordered_map>;
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps, but both classes have some other methods which differ between classes. So, in case I have `SingleThreadedParser::f1()' and `MultithreadedParser::f2()` where `f1` and `f2` have different signatures and implementations which use different members of these classes, could this approach be extended to support his? Am I correct that in this case I should inherit these to classes to this one and with this parametrization?

Comment: In this case you should clarify your question. We can write answers only to the questions that were actually asked. Also, are you aware that both `f1` and `f2` as part of the template, and that only the one that gets called gets actually instantiated, as part of the template's specific instance? There are some restrictions here, see your C++ textbook for more information.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, I never said that `f1` and `f2` must be a part of a template. I said that they belong to different (derived) classes, so do I don't see any issue to put them into derived classes in this case, as well, if they could be derived from `Parser`, let's say with [CRPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). The question is, if this is possible or I will need another trick for this.

Comment: What is funny, I used exactly the same solution in my [code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/289524/multithreaded-natural-language-text-parser) before I asked this question, I just somehow failed to see the place to implement the necessary function (to "merge" `TextBaseSingleThreaded::tokenize` and `TextBaseMultiThreaded::tokenize_chunk` in that case. Thank you, it helped.